# Assign a role using CSS instead of adding it to the HTML tags

Tags: html, css, accessibility

Is it possible to assign a role to all elements with a given class? I'd want to turn this:

```
<div class="a" role="button">Text!</div>
<div class="a" role="button">More text!</div>
```

into this

```
<div class="a">Text!</div>
<div class="a">More text!</div>
<style>
.a { 
  role: button
}
</style>
```

I've found solutions for filtering by role in css but nothing to assign a role to elements using css.

Comment: You cannot do this using css, css is not build to do these things. You need to use javascript.

Comment: Not to be "that guy" but any reason you can't change your HTML? I mean semantically a `<button>` is applicable and it solves about 20 headaches you have with your current `<div>` based "buttons". For example how do keyboard users use them? How is focus handled? Can i press enter to activate them etc. etc. There may be a good reason just thought I would ask why you need to do this without changing the HTML?

Answer (score 2):

```js
let buts = document.getElementsByClassName("a");

for(let i = 0; i < buts.length; i++){
  buts[i].setAttribute("role", "button");
}
```

```html
<div class="a">Text!</div>
<div class="a">More text!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve with pure JavaScript through **forEach()** method.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".a").forEach(function(role){
  role.setAttribute('role', 'button');  
});
```

```html
<div class="a">Text!</div>
<div class="a">Text #2</div>
<div class="a">More text!</div>
```